# With a single Javascript for Entire Website set on Master Page, how to exe a JS function only for one(or 2) chlid page

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, ajax, javascript-framework

I am working on a .net website with only a single Javascript (so far). Because I have been told Single JS get best performance etc. firstly, any suggestions on JS frameworks , any cutting-edged articles?

Secondly, I met some problems when I was trying to invoke JS function just for a child page. I tried something like :

1.I want to exe a function after a page_load (i.e. ispostback)

```
$("#div_ID").ready
```

2.exe a function after page postback (a dropdownlist post back in updatepanel)

```
pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(BeginHandler)

function BeginHandler()
{$(".DDL_ClassName").change(function{.....});
}
```

Both not work. System won't recognized the div or DDL.
I'm not able to set the function in $(document).ready or  .add_beginReqest() in the 'master' JS, it will cause errors on other pages. Any suggestions? or do I have to move to multiple JS files?

Moreover, instead of writing inline javascript, I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function{textchange});

function textchange(function { $(".textbox_class").change(.....)});
```

It works in Chrome etc, but not for IE 7 (mb IE8 as well)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple different ways you could do this.

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with having a $(document.ready( on each page.  Keep all your functions in a single .js file, but it is pretty handy (and still lightweight) to just have some simple init functions on each page.  In that case you would do the same thing you had:

```
//On the single page you want the function called on
$(document.ready(function() {
     textchange();
});
```

If you don't want to have a $(document).ready() on your child page, you could use an if statement in your .js file. Use window.location.pathname to get the path to your file, and check this against what it should be for your child page.  Your code might look like this :

```
//In your main .js file
$(document).ready(function() {
     if(window.location.pathname == "/childPage.htm")
          textchange();
});
```

Comment: Your method can work. Since my page url has different root path, running on different server.

Comment: Your method can work. Since my page url has different root path, running on different server. I use div.length = 0 to check wether it exists. is that ok?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with div.length .  Post some source code if you can't get it figured out.  However, the 'window.location.pathname' portion of my code should stop any errors from occurring due to your file structure - unless you have the child page in a new folder.  In that case change the if statement to : if(window.location.pathname == "/childfolder/childPage.htm") - but rename childFolder and childPage to the correct names.

Comment: thanks anyway, the case div.length == 0 means , the current has this div (found by ID or class).

Comment: I used find whether a html element instead.